# How to sort a list based on dictionary values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda

Given a list and a dict in the following format:

```
l = ["2D", "5H", "8S", "JC", "3H", "4S", "8C", "AD"]

d = {"3":1,  "4":2,  "5":3, "6":4, "7":5,
     "8":6,  "9":7,  "0":8, "J":9, "Q":10,
     "K":11, "A":12, "2":13}
```

How to sort the list based on the values in the dictionary?
I have tried to sort it by using `sorted` with a `lambda` function:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: d[x])
```

What is the mistake? Or is there any other better ways to sort it?

Thanks for telling me.

Comment: dont name it list ... but your example should do what you are asking ...

Comment: Note that `sorted` doesn't sort the list in-place, it returns a new copy of the list which is sorted... `result = sorted(...)`. See http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/803447-sorted-sort for more information

Comment: The elements in your list `["2D","5H",...]` are not in your dict. You will get key errors.

Comment: Yup, I get a key error. So how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stating the obvious, none of the elements in your list are keys in the dictionary.

*Perhaps* you just want to use the first letter of the list element? If so, you can do:

```
>>> li = ["2D","5H","8S", "JC", "3H", "4S", "8C", "AD"]
>>> di = {"3":1, "4":2, "5":3, "6":4, "7":5, "8":6, "9":7, "0":8, "J":9, "Q":10, "K":11, "A":12, "2":13}
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda k: di[k[0]])
['3H', '4S', '5H', '8S', '8C', 'JC', 'AD', '2D']
```

If there is a possibility that the key is not present in the dict, you can use [{}.get()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to provide a default weighting:

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda k: di.get(k[0], 0))
['3H', '4S', '5H', '8S', '8C', 'JC', 'AD', '2D']
```

Note: Don't name variables `dict` and `list` or you may be surprised sometimes when you try and call the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) and [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> list=[1,2,3]
>>> list('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```